# Custom css for block and page in drupal views

Tags: css, drupal, content-management-system

I have a custom view, that has page and block. But the problem when i styled block, same styles applied to the page. How do i create another css rules for page or block?

Comment: In Drupal lingo, a page might contain several views and blocks, but not the other way around. Please update your question.

Comment: I mean this: http://d.pr/i/5xXr
How to create 1.css for page and 2.css for block?
If i change CSS name at 3, it changes on block\page aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the css class, it assumes you want to do so globally!  To apply your css changes just for a page or  block, select 'This page' or 'This block' from the drop-down, so it's not applied GLOBALLY.

Let me know if that solved your issue!  :-)

[image]